# Get info about properties declared in categories

Tags: iphone, objective-c, runtime, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to obtain the type info about UIView properties but it simply doesn't work, `class_getProperty` always returns `NULL`. I believe this is somehow connected to categories, because many of the properties on UIView are defined in categories.

```
objc_property_t prop = class_getProperty([object class], "backgroundColor");
```

Is there any workaround for this problem?

Comment: Why not use view.backgroundColor ? what exactly do you want to do with this property ?

Comment: @giorashc I need a property type to perform data conversion.

Comment: @giorashc I do this in runtime and property names are loaded dynamically, so I cannot directly address a property since there can be any of them.

Comment: I never tried it but I think the reason you do not see them is because they are meant to be private (visible only in the implementation file). UIView is a class Apple do not want you to mess with. You can always subclass it and add your own members. Can you give an example for the purpose of this approach ?

Comment: @giorashc UIView.backgroundColor is a public property that can be directly accessed or via Key-value coding. So it looks a bit spooky that UIView interface properties are accessible and category-related props are not. I guess there's some magic in categories, which are according to 2.0 runtime changes sealed with object in the end AFAIK. Regarding the purpose: data bindings.

Comment: Categories can't actually add properties to a class, they only add the syntactic sugar. You will need to go the KVC route here, unfortunately.

Comment: But the class should still have a metadata entry for it, @RichardJ.RossIII, however it's implemented: https://gist.github.com/woolsweater/5978625

Comment: @JoshCaswell It's quite possible it's a bug, but seeing as you cannot `@synthesize` properties in a category, it *does* make sense that you can't add properties to the class's metadata through categories.

Comment: You can absolutely add properties to categories. Using the objective-c runtime you can create associated objects